# templates extensions cannot work when I add another tag name

Tags: django, python-3.x, web

In [my base.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nh1Sa.jpg) I have add a template named`{% block tags}`,and corresponding tag in [my tag.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ib6Hy.jpg),I really confusing why it doesn't work

Comment: Please, post your code as plain text. It will help the community to give the answers.

Comment: ok, I 'm clear of that, but how to add code

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work. Can you include the views (the python code) and the outputs too?

Comment: `{% block tags %}
        <span class="w3-tag w3-light-grey w3-small w3-margin-bottom">12456</span>
{% endblock %}`when I replace 123456 into a template var, it wouldn't work; interestingly, this var in other block works well